# Using Gatsby how to link to a static html file and open in the same page?

Tags: history, gatsby

So I have my gatbsy blog with a link `<a href="static.html">static</a>`. But when I click it says that gatsby can't find the page. Now I need to reload to actually get the static.html file.

Note that I'm using a simple a tag and not the gatsby-link. I'm not using pushState from history, so not sure how it actually does a soft load.

I want to open in the same page, not target _blank like the how has been "solved" here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2928

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you storing your static.html? I put a sample static.html in my `src/static` folder, link to it with an `<a href="/static.html">static</a>` tag from my index page and it works fine.

Comment: Interesting is not working fine on mine. I have the same setup as you. Do you have this hosted somewhere? maybe is one of my plugins that is doing this magic :( I can't figure out what is doing this behavior.

Comment: No I just quickly tried it out in a gatsby site I'm working on... perhaps it's helpful if you post your `gatsby-config.js` here?

Answer (score 0):

That should normally work. Perhaps you've installed https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-catch-links/?=cstc which is catching the link and trying to resolve it within Gatsby?

Comment: I actually want to refresh the page. That plugin is to avoid the refresh if I read correctly? "Intercepts local links from markdown and other non-react pages and does a client-side pushState to avoid the browser having to refresh the page." I want to load the html from the server again.